# PHP Form Screws up Link

Tags: php, forms, post, hyperlink, href

I am trying to make an online system where people can send leads html emails, from within the system...

I have everything working except for when I put in links with the rich text editor, and everything looks fine in the source, but when I look at the email in my inbox, the link doesnt work and has changed to:

> x-msg://30/%22http://example.com/%22

which I dont understand...

I think it is a problem with the html post function as I am submitting it through and html form with `$_POST` method...  And when I echo the statement on the next page, the link is *`http://workwithmandy.co/%22http://phobes.com/%22`*, which is weird because the root of the site that the system is on is *`http://workwithmandy.co/`* .

Any Ideas on why this is??

**Here is the form:**

```
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="POST" name="form" id="sendemailform">
          <fieldset>
          <div class="emailtablecontainer">
          <table width="525" border="0" cellspacing="10">
  <tr>
    <td><label>To:</label></td>
    <td><select data-placeholder="Select Lead(s) To Email..." multiple="true" class="chzn-container-multi" name="selectleads"style="width:500px;">
            <?php
do {  
?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row_rsAllLeads['Email']?>"><?php echo $row_rsAllLeads['FullName']?></option>
            <?php
} while ($row_rsAllLeads = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsAllLeads));
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($rsAllLeads);
  if($rows > 0) {
      mysql_data_seek($rsAllLeads, 0);
      $row_rsAllLeads = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsAllLeads);
  }
?>
          </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>Subject:</label></td>
    <td><input class="inputs" name="subjectfield" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>Message:</label></td>
    <td><textarea id="sendemailtextarea" name="messagefield"></textarea></td>
    <script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'sendemailtextarea',
    {
        toolbar : 'SendEmailToolbar'
    });
    </script>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<input class="submitemailbuttonsprite submitemailbutton1" name="submitemail" type="submit" value="Send Email(s)">
          </fieldset>
          <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form">
          </form>
```

**And Here Is The Actual Php Code:**

```
<?php
$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form")) {
    echo $_POST['messagefield'];
 $to = $_POST['selectleads'];
 $subject = $_POST['subjectfield'];
 $body = $_POST['messagefield'];
 $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
 $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
 $headers .= "From: " . $row_rs_CurrentUser['FirstName'] . " " . $row_rs_CurrentUser['LastName'] . " <" . $row_rs_CurrentUser['Email'] . ">";
 if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
  } else {
   echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
  }
}
?>
```

**COMPLETE GENERATED HTML CODE AFTER SUBMITTING FORM:**

```
<p>
    <a href=\"http://www.amazon.com\">Hello</a></p>

<!doctype html>
<html><head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width = 1300">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Back Office | Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../chosen/chosen.css">
<script src="../chosen/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".chzn-container-multi").chosen();
});
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Style Sheets/styles.css"/>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div align="center">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="welcome">
    <strong>Welcome, Alex | </strong><a href="/BackOffice/Home.php?doLogout=true">Logout</a>
    </div>
    <div class="header">
    </div>
    <!--end header-->
    <div class="content_wrapper">
      <div class="main_content">
        <div class="sidebar">
          <div class="sidebar_main">
            <div class="menu_holder">
              <h1>Control Panel</h1>
              <ul class="menu_items">
                <li class="menu-1"><a href="Home.php">Home</a></li>
                <li class="menu-2"><a href="Manage Leads.php" class="current">Manage Leads</a></li>
                <li class="menu-3"><a href="Manage Autoresponses.php">Manage Autoresponses</a></li>
                <li class="menu-4"><a href="My NMVT.php">My NMVT</a></li>
                <li class="menu-5"><a href="Home.php">Lead Capture Settings</a></li>
                <li class="menu-6"><a href="Home.php">Appointments</a></li>
                <li class="menu-7"><a href="Home.php">Resources</a></li>
                <li class="menu-8"><a href="Home.php">Referral System</a></li>
                <li class="menu-9"><a href="Home.php">My Account</a></li>
                <li class="menu-10"><a href="Contact Support.php">Contact Support</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--end sidebar-->
        <div class="content">
          <div class="content_container">
          <div class="page_container">
          <div class="content_page_header">
          <span>Send Email</span>
          </div>
          <div class="box_container">
          <form action="/BackOffice/Send Email.php?" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" name="form" id="sendemailform">
          <fieldset>
          <div class="emailtablecontainer">
          <table width="525" border="0" cellspacing="10">
  <tr>
    <td><label>To:</label></td>
    <td><select data-placeholder="Select Lead(s) To Email..." multiple="true" class="chzn-container-multi" name="selectleads"style="width:500px;">
                        <option value="acorso@gmail.com">Alex Corso</option>
                        <option value="Praesent.luctus.Curabitur@velturpis.edu">Aline Church</option>
                        <option value="tincidunt.Donec@necante.com">Ariana Gay</option>
                        <option value="aburks@gmail.com">Artie Burkinshaw</option>
                        <option value="daaghewi@gmail.com">asdfqphgp</option>
                        <option value="Nulla@Nuncac.ca">Avram Robbins</option>
                        <option value="auctor.nunc@Maurisvestibulumneque.ca">Bethany Church</option>
                        <option value="luctus@ettristiquepellentesque.ca">Byron Jordan</option>
                        <option value="nascetur@velarcueu.ca">Camille Hughes</option>
                        <option value="posuere.vulputate@orci.com">Cecilia Glenn</option>
                        <option value="fringilla@Aliquamtinciduntnunc.edu">Chancellor Henry</option>
                        <option value="in@estNuncullamcorper.edu">Charity Osborn</option>
                        <option value="blandit@Crasdolor.ca">Cheryl Koch</option>
                        <option value="Ut@sapiengravidanon.edu">Claire Kirby</option>
                        <option value="tristique@pharetra.ca">Clinton Mccall</option>
                        <option value="iaculis@Vestibulumaccumsan.ca">Colleen Craft</option>
                        <option value="kraft323@gmail.com">Connor Kraft</option>
                        <option value="posuere.cubilia.Curae;@etmagnis.edu">Courtney Cole</option>
                        <option value="Praesent@nonvestibulumnec.com">Cyrus Reed</option>
                        <option value="augue.ut@nibhlacinia.org">Dane Love</option>
                        <option value="turpis@felis.org">Danielle Sandoval</option>
                        <option value="webb@gmail.com">Darius Web</option>
                        <option value="dcallihan@yahoo.com">Dennis Callihan</option>
                        <option value="asdgq@hand.com">dgwertq</option>
                        <option value="luctus.ipsum@ullamcorpermagna.ca">Dolan Powers</option>
                        <option value="Etiam.imperdiet.dictum@ascelerisquesed.org">Dominique Higgins</option>
                        <option value="mauris.elit.dictum@enimnislelementum.edu">Echo Michael</option>
                        <option value="ipsum.Suspendisse.sagittis@tellus.org">Edan Pacheco</option>
                        <option value="risus.Nunc@ligulaeu.ca">Evangeline Eaton</option>
                        <option value="massa.Mauris@turpisNullaaliquet.com">Fallon Dyer</option>
                        <option value="elit.a.feugiat@etmagnis.com">Ferris Velez</option>
                        <option value="Email@gnail.com">Full Namehshs</option>
                        <option value="id@elementumsemvitae.ca">Gail Goodwin</option>
                        <option value="venenatis@massa.org">Gareth Austin</option>
                        <option value="Duis@volutpatNullafacilisis.com">Geoffrey Caldwell</option>
                        <option value="posuere.enim@Phasellusdolor.ca">Geoffrey Pollard</option>
                        <option value="gmandel@gmail.com">Gregory Mandel</option>
                        <option value="Morbi@nislMaecenasmalesuada.edu">Griffith Bradley</option>
                        <option value="Maecenas@Phasellus.edu">Halee Mann</option>
                        <option value="lorem@fames.com">Hannah Booth</option>
                        <option value="magna@vulputatemauris.edu">Haviva Hobbs</option>
                        <option value="nunc@sitamet.org">Hermione Barton</option>
                        <option value="Aenean@odio.ca">Illiana Vasquez</option>
                        <option value="Curabitur.ut@mifelisadipiscing.edu">Imelda Madden</option>
                        <option value="dictum.eleifend.nunc@Duissit.org">Inez Newton</option>
                        <option value="iparks@gmail.com">Isaiah Parks</option>
                        <option value="dui.Fusce@dui.ca">Jaden Joyner</option>
                        <option value="ac.libero.nec@augue.org">Jakeem Walters</option>
                        <option value="jmishoe@gmail.com">James Mishoe</option>
                        <option value="purus.ac.tellus@in.edu">Jana Edwards</option>
                        <option value="eu.nibh@posuere.edu">Jenette Smith</option>
                        <option value="jcasablanca@gmail.com">John Casablanca</option>
                        <option value="Nunc@Crasvulputate.org">Joseph Morris</option>
                        <option value="enim.consequat@lectusquismassa.edu">Kameko Weaver</option>
                        <option value="Proin.vel@maurisanunc.edu">Kane Newman</option>
                        <option value="in.aliquet.lobortis@luctusipsumleo.ca">Karleigh Henry</option>
                        <option value="cursus.vestibulum@enimsit.com">Keith Arnold</option>
                        <option value="mus@sodales.ca">Kenyon Salas</option>
                        <option value="tortor.dictum.eu@acturpis.org">Kessie Strong</option>
                        <option value="Donec.luctus.aliquet@metusAliquam.com">Kiara Santiago</option>
                        <option value="Suspendisse.sagittis.Nullam@euismodest.ca">Kiona Cabrera</option>
                        <option value="nisi.sem@Donecporttitor.com">Knox Roberts</option>
                        <option value="enim.sit@idblandit.ca">Lacota Ortiz</option>
                        <option value="in@venenatis.com">Laith Roach</option>
                        <option value="sollicitudin.adipiscing.ligula@luctusvulputate.com">Lani Berry</option>
                        <option value="vitae@loremsitamet.com">Linda Parker</option>
                        <option value="loisg@gmail.com">Lois Griffin</option>
                        <option value="facilisis.eget.ipsum@ipsum.org">Lucas Mason</option>
                        <option value="ligula.tortor.dictum@aliquet.com">Macey Snider</option>
                        <option value="Duis.gravida@iaculislacus.edu">Magee Ramirez</option>
                        <option value="euismod.urna@etultricesposuere.org">Mariko Barton</option>
                        <option value="mfulps@gmail.com">Marshawn Fulps</option>
                        <option value="ornare.elit.elit@magnaa.com">Maryam Andrews</option>
                        <option value="libero@pharetranibhAliquam.org">Megan Stewart</option>
                        <option value="pede.blandit.congue@Cras.org">Melinda Stokes</option>
                        <option value="feugiat.nec.diam@auctor.ca">Natalie Humphrey</option>
                        <option value="ultrices.Duis.volutpat@egettinciduntdui.com">Nathan Mcmahon</option>
                        <option value="orci.quis.lectus@Integerurna.org">Nathaniel Mcleod</option>
                        <option value="ipsum.Donec@erat.edu">Noel Munoz</option>
                        <option value="Etiam@Donectincidunt.org">Ocean Foley</option>
                        <option value="est@velitQuisque.edu">Pamela Morton</option>
                        <option value="rutrum@faucibusorci.edu">Pearl Tate</option>
                        <option value="placerat@variusultricesmauris.edu">Perry Medina</option>
                        <option value="pgriffin@gmail.com">Peter Griffin</option>
                        <option value="ipsum@ridiculus.com">Philip Hatfield</option>
                        <option value="pstuff88@gmail.com">Philip Stuff</option>
                        <option value="Morbi.metus@Inscelerisque.com">Plato Hatfield</option>
                        <option value="tempor.erat@loremeget.edu">Quintessa Stephens</option>
                        <option value="adipiscing.elit.Curabitur@Integer.com">Rama Huber</option>
                        <option value="eu@Phasellusin.ca">Rana Whitfield</option>
                        <option value="Nunc@etcommodo.org">Randall Barnett</option>
                        <option value="rdemi@gmail.com">Rashiki Demisola</option>
                        <option value="nunc@variusultrices.ca">Ray Scott</option>
                        <option value="adipiscing.elit.Etiam@cursusnonegestas.edu">Roary Stout</option>
                        <option value="auctor.velit@nuncQuisque.ca">Ross Frost</option>
                        <option value="rwhitworth@inbox.com">Rubyona Whitworth</option>
                        <option value="asgawehgiasdo@gmail.com">Sahwod Adams</option>
                        <option value="mattis@Phasellus.com">Shaine Goodman</option>
                        <option value="sdhageng@gmail.com">Sharod Enlingson</option>
                        <option value="shadams@gmail.com">Shenequa Adams</option>
                        <option value="et@aliquamarcuAliquam.org">Sophia Green</option>
                        <option value="Maecenas@Morbi.ca">Stella Knight</option>
                        <option value="lorem@arcu.com">Tate Good</option>
                        <option value="in@vehiculaetrutrum.edu">Teagan Dudley</option>
                        <option value="lacus.vestibulum@pede.ca">Vaughan Huff</option>
                        <option value="Vestibulum.ut@enimnectempus.ca">Whoopi Ratliff</option>
                        <option value="et@mi.com">Xander Monroe</option>
                        <option value="et.magnis.dis@sapiengravidanon.com">Xanthus Williams</option>
                        <option value="sagittis.Nullam.vitae@atrisusNunc.edu">Xavier Wilkinson</option>
                        <option value="rhoncus.Nullam.velit@nonduinec.com">Zenaida Day</option>
                        <option value="adfg@gmail.com">zzzzzza</option>
                      </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>Subject:</label></td>
    <td><input class="inputs" name="subjectfield" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>Message:</label></td>
    <td><textarea id="sendemailtextarea" name="messagefield"></textarea></td>
    <script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'sendemailtextarea',
    {
        toolbar : 'SendEmailToolbar'
    });
    </script>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<input class="submitemailbuttonsprite submitemailbutton1" name="submitemail" type="submit" value="Send Email(s)">
          </fieldset>
          <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form">
          </form>
          </div>
          <div class="content_page_footer">
          </div>
          <!--end content_container-->
        </div>
        <!--end content-->
      </div>
      <!--end main_content-->
    </div>
    <!--end content_wrapper-->
  </div>
  <!--end wrapper-->
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="text_wrapper">
      <p>Copyright © 2012 PROCapture LLC</p>
      <p>Privacy Policy  |  Terms And Conditions</p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the generated HTML code of your form?

Comment: Good Question...  Give me a minute...

Comment: If I put a link in the rich text editor, and the source looks like this: "<p><a href="http://www.amazon.com">Hello</a></p>" it will output this: "<p><a href="\&quot;http://www.amazon.com\&quot;">Hello</a></p>" ...  Which actually makes me start to think this is a quotes problem :)

Comment: That was the code from the form echoed in PHP by the way... I assume thats what you meant...

Comment: Use"View source" in your browser to see the HTML source. Click "edit" below the question to add content to the question.

Comment: That was what you were looking for, right?

Comment: ACTUALLY I JUST FIGURED OUT HOW TO MAKE IT WORK!!!  But I dont know what I need to do...  I need to make it so that the source code that CKEditor writes does not include any quotes...  For example, instead of <a href="www.example.com"></a> i want it to write <a href=www.example.com></a>..